# Orange 3 "Find Informative Projections" and target variables?

Tags: prediction, orange, plotting

Having issues with the "find informative projections" feature in Orange 3. In order to be able to use this feature in the scatterplots, you have to select a target variable in the "select columns". So I choose the value that I'm most interested in finding correlations to. However, whatever I choose as a target variable doesn't show up in the informative projections list as being correlated to other features in my data set. Why not?

I have a lot of features in my data and was under the impression that the "find informative projections" option finds pairs of features that seem to have a linear correlation and sorts them by which pairs are most correlated.

If that's the case, why do you need a target variable? How do I choose an appropriate target variable?

Am I misunderstanding the purpose of the "find informative projections" feature?

I'm attaching a pic of my work flow.
[image: Orange data workflow]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, "find informative projections" gives you the best pair of features ("score plots") to explain the target variable. The two best features will be on the x- and y-axis, while your target variable will be the **color** (hue for numeric, categorical otherwise).

Here is an example for the Iris dataset. Where "iris" is the target --> color, and petal length and petal width are the most informative features, followed by petal width and sepal width, and so on.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I've seen that example before. What I don't understand is why if iris is the target variable it does not show up in that list as being correlated to petal length or sepal width, etc. I was hoping it would give me a list of the top pairs of features that are highly correlated, or have the highest r-squared value or something. This seems like it's going one step deeper. What kind of analysis is it doing to come up with these projections?

Comment: for a given target $y$ the it gives you the best two features $(x_j,x_k)$ that predict $y$. If you don't want tuples of features, you can use the `rank` widget for regression or the `preprocessing` widget with `select relevant features` for classification

Answer (score 1):

Slightly related with the question (issues with Find Informative Projections), I found this post trying to solve this issue: the tool Find Informative Projections was disabled and Orange did not provide any hint about why.

In the end the issue was on my side: I forgot to set any variable as Target when loading the data so it was useless to select it in the Scatter Plot points-colors section.

Double click on the File to load the data where you can choose if a variable is categorical or numerical, then double click on the variable I wanted to use as Target (that was marked as Feature) in order to select it as Target and the Find Informative Projections was enabled again.

PS: I have also noted that when making predictions, the file loaded should have all variables marked as Features. If you mark as before one of the variables as target, Orange shows a red circle with an exclamation mark on the Predictions widget, and a message: **"Data does not have the same target as predictors"** (even though it is). I guess that the target in the prediction file is automatically set by checking which info is missing in the file.